# GridView Items not showing until i enter another activity and return

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView, and 2 items, when i enter the app only one item is shown, but if i enter an activity within the app and return, it shows the second item, i don't know what's the problem .

CustomGrid :

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter
{
private final int[] Imageid;
private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;

public CustomGrid(Context paramContext, String[] paramArrayOfString, int[] paramArrayOfInt1)
{
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    this.Imageid = paramArrayOfInt1;
    this.web = paramArrayOfString;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return this.web.length;
}

public Object getItem(int paramInt)
{
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int paramInt)
{
    return 0L;
}

public View getView(int paramInt, View view, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
{
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.grid_single, null);
    }
    else
    {
        TextView Text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView localImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        Text.setText(this.web[paramInt]);
        localImageView.setImageResource(this.Imageid[paramInt]);
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

MainActivity :

```
        CustomGrid localCustomGrid = new CustomGrid(this, this.web, this.imageId);
    this.grid = ((GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid));
    this.grid.setAdapter(localCustomGrid);
```

Comment: Still happens if you `return imageid[paramInt]` in `public long getItemId(int paramInt)` ? I currently don't have the chance to see the entire code. Hope my guess would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, still the same.

Comment: Sorry I meant `return paramInt` instead of `return Imageid[paramInt]`. Excuse me for not being able to look at it all.

Comment: Well, still the same no changing.

Comment: No need to solve, I've switched to RecyclerView and it's working well.

Comment: One way to solve problems is to destroy them. Celebrate it with a cup of coffee :-)